# I want to update my FormGroup with a If condition

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-forms

This is my FormGroup

```
repairFacilityForm = new FormGroup({

languageTypeId: new FormControl("", Validators.required),
repairFacilityId: new FormControl(""),
timeZone: new FormControl("", Validators.required),
name: new FormControl("", Validators.required),
address: new FormControl("", Validators.required),
branch: new FormControl(""),
```

})

I want to update this branch as a required one inside an If condition.I tried to like this

```
  if(distributorId > 0) {

    this.repairFacilityForm = new FormGroup({
      branch: new FormControl("", Validators.required)

  });
```

}

But It is not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use setValidators to add validator

```
this.repairFacilityForm.controls["branch"].setValidators(Validators.required);
```

Comment: repairFacilityForm = new FormGroup({...,branch: (distributorId > 0)?new FormControl("",Validators.required):new FormControl("")});

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
languageTypeId: new FormControl("", [Validators.required]),
```

Add Validation in Array Block